# DataSet Not supported Nullable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model, crystal-reports, nullable

i am working on crystal report and getting "DataSet not supported Nullable" exception.i search it on google and found many solution but i still did not get how to convert empty column into null using null-coalescing operator ternary operator in where clause.

below is my code

```
          ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
        // rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "CrystalReport.rpt"));
        rd.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/CrystalReportForSingle.rpt"));
        rd.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "786", @"NUMAN-PC", "DiaryManagementSystem");
        DiaryManagementSystemEntities1 db = new DiaryManagementSystemEntities1();
        // rd.SetDataSource(DataSetToList.ToDataSet(db.File_Movement.Where(x => x.file_Id == id).ToList()));

        rd.SetDataSource(db.File_Movement.Where(x => x.file_Id == id).ToList());
        Response.Buffer = false;
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();

        try
        {

            Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return File(stream, "application/pdf", "DiaryMovementList.pdf");

        }
        catch
        {

            throw;
        }

        return View();

    }
```

i have more multiple column of type DateTime in my Table which are empty and need to convert null before passing to crystal report DataSet but i dont know how to convert those columns in where clause method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but you can send them as formula or as parameter.

Formula example:

```
var formula = "DATE({CreatedDate}) >= DATE('30.04.2019')";
rpt.RecordSelectionFormula = formula;
```

Parameter example:

```
rpt.SetParameterValue("CreatedDate", "30.04.2019");
```